# Y Combinator in Scheme using Define

Tags: lisp, scheme, lambda-calculus, combinators, y-combinator

In order to learn what a fixed-point combinator is and is used for, I wrote my own. But instead of writing it with strictly anonymous functions, like [Wikipedia's example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator#Example_in_scheme), I just used define:

```
(define combine (lambda (functional)
                  (functional (lambda args (apply (combine functional) args))))
```

I've tested this with functionals for factorial and fibonacci, and it seems to work. Does this meet the formal definition of a fixed-point combinator?

Comment: Exercise 2: Y combinator without using `define` or `letrec` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, because according to [the blog referred to in the previous answer](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html), it doesn't even meet the definition of *combinator*, since  'combine' is a free variable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Just to be sure that the blog's definition is correct, do you consider it equivalent to Wikipedia's definition: "A combinator is a higher-order function that uses only function application and earlier defined combinators to define a result from its arguments."? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: While chessweb or anyone else corroborates his answer, temporarily consider his answer correct and this one wrong.

---

It seems the answer is yes. Apparently the exact same combinator appears [here](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html), midway down the page:

```
(define Y
    (lambda (f)
      (f (lambda (x) ((Y f) x)))))
```

Comment: You shouldn't. You're encouraged to answer you own questions. IIRC you can accept your own answer in 2 days after you gave it.

Comment: The main point of teaching the Y combinator is to see how you can *implement* recursion with just functions.  By writing a recursive definition, you fail to do that -- so you end up with something that works, but it's only useful in understanding what Y is supposed to do.  Mike's text would be a good place to read about it in depth and see how the `define`-less version is derived.